# how to get global p for categorical variables in svy_vglm

Tags: r, survey, multinomial

I'm using the function `svyVGAM::svy_vglm`  to run a multinomial model with survey weights:

```
mmodel <- svy_glm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4..., family=multinomial, design=w_data)
```

where `x` represent categorical variables, some with three or more levels. Through model summary, I can know the p-value for each coefficient, but I don't know how to get the p-value for the global variable.

In other contexts, `anova()`, `waldtest()`, `lrtest()`, ... could be used, but none of them seem to work with svy_vglm objects. `tbl_regression` does not work either: `Error: No tidy method for objects of class svy_vglm`.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `coef` and `vcov` methods. There's probably a package, but it's not hard to program

Suppose that `model` is your model object, `design` is your survey design object and `index` is a vector with the positions of the coefficients you want to test. If you had ten coefficients and wanted to test all except the first two, you would have `index<-3:10`, for example.

```
beta<-coef(model)[index]
V<-vcov(model)[index,index]
teststat <- crossprod(beta, solve(V,beta))
pf(teststat, df1=length(beta), df2=degf(design), lower.tail=FALSE)
```

This doesn't give you a likelihood ratio test; you'd probably need to write to the package author and suggest that as a new feature.